# Virtuemart - Change "add to cart" to link elsewhere

Tags: php, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I want my virtuemart 2 shop to lead people to a contact form, or external link when they click on "Add to cart" button. I want to be able to change the link behind this button. How is this possible?

So far, I have only found where the template is being called in the product page template (components/com_virtuemart/views/productdetails/tmpl/default.php):

```
<?php

    // Add To Cart Button

        // if (!empty($this->product->prices) and !empty($this->product->images[0]) and $this->product->images[0]->file_is_downloadable==0 ) {

    // if (!VmConfig::get('use_as_catalog', 0) and !empty($this->product->prices['salesPrice'])) {

        echo $this->loadTemplate('addtocart');

// }  // Add To Cart Button END

    ?>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Nobody has an ideea of this? It should be pretty basic, although I can not seem to find the actual linking.

Answer (score 0):

(components/com_virtuemart/views/productdetails/tmpl/default_addtocart.php) is the PHP looking for.

On and around line 123 the following lines occur:

```
<span class="addtocart-button">
    <?php echo shopFunctionsF::getAddToCartButton ($this->product->orderable);
      // Display the add to cart button END  ?>
</span>
```

Change the PHP echo into a:

```
<a href="yourwebsite.com/thelinkyouwanthere.php">Buy Product</a>
```

Or something similar to that.

```
<span class="addtocart-button">
    <a href="yourwebsite.com/thelinkyouwanthere.php">Buy Product</a>
</span>
```

Hope this helps.